# Create ASP.NET GridView automatically with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to make a general Gridview and then I've got some SQL tables which I want to fill in.

The columns and rows should be automatically generated if there are more.
I will use C# to do that. But how do I do it if I want to generate the rows and columns automatically?

Comment: `Rows.Add()` and `Columns.Add()`?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You may use the [AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) property of gridview. Set it as true and just give the source to gridview

Comment: @sohaiby But I can't give the source inside the ASP.NET because the query is also written inside the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the property `AutoGenerateColumns` should be set `true`

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GV1" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

then you just have to bind your data in codebehind:

```
string Command = "SELECT This, That FROM YourTable WHERE YourCondition = @YC;";
using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
{
    using (MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command, myConnection))
    {
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@YC", "foo"));
        DataTable YourDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(YourDataTable);
        GV1.DataSource = YourDataTable;
        GV1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: @fusionchart_help updated - for example or at a buttonclick but i would run it not everey postback (`if (!Page.IsPostBack)`)

Comment: add `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` at the top of your page

Comment: what is the usage for the MySqlParameter?